# queried string result in <p> tag and break string to be in new line

Tags: php, html, css

I have a `description` field in one of my table in my database. I want to display it in a paragraph form, however, the problem is that if the string is too long, I want to break it and continue the string in a new line. How am I going to do it?

```
<p align="justify" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: underline"> 
    <?php echo $item[0]->description;?>
</p>
```

Comment: the browser will break it once it reaches the end of the container; so just set the containers width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wordwrap

```
<?php echo wordwrap($item[0]->description,30,"<br>\n");?>
```

Here new line will be there automatically on every 30th character ,you can change it to your convinience

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
.text
{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

here's the jsfiddle;

[New Line](https://jsfiddle.net/esGEn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

word-wrap to break the line.

```
p{word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wordwrap in php http://www.w3schools.com

/php/func_string_wordwrap.asp

```
<?php
$str = "An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic";
echo wordwrap($str,15,"<br>\n");
?>
```